# Android - Invoke activity from within jar

Tags: android, jar, android-activity

I have a jar that consists of a class that extends Activity and performs some activity on onCreate. I want to import this jar into my Android app and start the activity.

How can I go about this?

Thanks 
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #1: Put the JAR in your project's `libs/` directory.

Step #2: If you are using Eclipse, add this JAR to your build path

Comment: what if he's not using eclipse?

Comment: Ok. After that, can I just create an Intent object and supply the package name and class name, and then call the startActivity?

Comment: I did that: put the JAR in libs, and the JAR to build path and add the activity in manifest <activity
            android:name="com.telecoming.sms_payment.Subscription"
            android:label="@string/app_name"> but in logCat says FATAL EXCEPTION: main ActivityNotFoundException. Any idea??
        </activity>

Comment: @Ivan: Make sure you are on the latest SDK tools and ADT plugin, then undo your manual change to the build path -- just having the JAR in `libs/` should be sufficient. If that does not help, ask a fresh StackOverflow question, where you include your manifest and your entire stack trace.

Comment: I have SDK Tools v21.1, I remove the jar file from Build path and just having the jar in libs but the FATAL EXCEPTION continues

Comment: this is my new question maybe you can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569620/i-cant-call-an-activity-from-a-jar-file Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. I put the JAR in the assets folder, and didnt have to set the build path. Thanks a lot!